# How can I print result for each first (arr1) string index?

Tags: java

This code prints only the first index, I mean, when I type "am" it prints "ma". Now what I want is get results for all indices, please. I mean, let's say I type "am", "bm", I want the code to print "ma" and "mb" and etc.

```
String[] arr1 = { "am", "bm", "cm" };
String[] arr2 = { "ma", "mb", "mc" };
            
            
            btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
                    String line = textPane.getText();
                    
                    String arr[] = line.split(" ");

                    String firstWord = arr[0];
                    
                    if (Arrays.asList(arr1).contains(firstWord)) {
                    
                    int index = Arrays.asList(arr1).indexOf(firstWord);
                    
                    System.out.println(arr2[index]);
                    }                   

                    }}
                
                );
```

**** (edited version)

```
String[] arr1 = { "am", "bm", "cm" };
String[] arr2 = { "ma", "mb", "mc" };
                

            
            btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            
                    String line = textPane.getText();
                    
                    String arr[] = line.split(" ");

                    for (String i : arr) {
                    
                    if (Arrays.asList(arr1).contains(arr)) {
                        
                    int index = Arrays.asList(arr1).indexOf(arr);
                    
                    System.out.println(arr2[index]);
                    }       }           

                    
                    }}
                
                );
```

Comment: `String firstWord = arr[0];` it works fine already when the value of this `String` is changed to other values such as "cm".  If you want the value for all of `arr`, just add a loop that iterates through `arr` and sets the `String` each iteration?

Comment: I did but it didn't work. I tried all "for each loop" combination but no result.

Comment: There is something I miss, but I can't figure out what((

Comment: Post what you tried then, because in the current state there is nothing wrong with the code, other than you did not loop over the array and simply hard coded the first value

Comment: String[] arr1 = { "am", "bm", "lom" };
    String[] arr2 = { "dam", "dbm", "cl" };
    
    
    btnNewButton_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
      String line = textPane.getText();
      
      String arr[] = line.split(" ");

      for (String i : arr) {
      
      if (Arrays.asList(arr1).contains(arr)) {
       
      int index = Arrays.asList(arr1).indexOf(arr);
      
      System.out.println(arr2[index]);
      }  }   

      
      }}
     
     );

Comment: In your new code, the loop should be `.contains(i)` instead of `.contains(arr)` and `.indexOf(i)` instead of `.indexOf(arr)`, then it should work

Comment: Yeah now it works, I'm very greatful, God bless you!!!